# Alternative to scale! for SubArray objects

Tags: julia

I've heard that `SubArray` and other array operations are [eventually due for a performance overhaul](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7941) in the future. For the time being, I've had some fairly minor slowdowns in my code due to `SubArray` being slow. Here's an example:

```
A=rand(Float32,20000,20000);
B=sub(A,2:19999,2:19999);
@time scale!(A,0.2f0);
@time scale!(B,0.2f0);
```

resulting in

```
elapsed time: 0.245619038 seconds
elapsed time: 11.706939438 seconds
```

and so `scale!` is about 40-50 times slower on a similarly-sized `SubArray` than on an `Array`.

Is there a simple workaround I can use for `scale!` on `SubArray`'s for the time being? Or should I just wait for improvements in the next release?

If there are no workarounds, it's not a big problem, I was just curious.

Answer (score 3):

If you're up for it, it would not be particularly hard to radically improve the performance. `scale!` just needs an implementation that uses cartesian (multidimensional), rather than linear, indexing. For the moment, that does mean you have to use what might be unfamiliar syntax of [`Base.Cartesian`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/devdocs/cartesian/).

The core code for `scale!` [is here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/79ce765b3b8407e8eab4b7eff9aab0e89ed605be/base/linalg/generic.jl#L15-L21). You would want to make it look more similar to [this implementation of `copy!`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/79ce765b3b8407e8eab4b7eff9aab0e89ed605be/base/multidimensional.jl#L181-L185). The function body would literally change by two characters (adding `s*` to the RHS of that assignment).

Of course, if you're wanting to stick with Julia 0.3, your best bet is to use your own custom implementation.